# XDSoft DateTimePicker - disable sundays

Tags: datetimepicker

Is it possible to disable all specified weekdays in XDSoft DateTimePicker, for example all (and only) Sundays? How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

try this.

```
function disabledWeekdays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    //0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday , 3 is Wednesday, 4 is Thursday, 5 is Friday and 6 is Saturday
    if (day == 1 || day == 2 ||day == 3 ||day == 4 ||day == 5 ||day == 6) {
        return [false] ; 
    } else { 
        return [true] ;
    }
}

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({

beforeShowDay: disabledWeekdays

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only today (after over a year) I successfully tried your code.

Comment: Didn't notice that there 'beforeShowDay' exists. This is more readable than onGenerate.

Answer (score 2):

Create a if statement same as 'xdsoft_weekend' in the jquery.datetimepicker.js file as below.

```
if (start.getDay() === 0 || start.getDay() === 6 || options.weekends.indexOf(start.dateFormat(options.formatDate)) !== -1) {
    classes.push('xdsoft_weekend');
}

if (start.getDay() === 0 || options.weekends.indexOf(start.dateFormat(options.formatDate)) !== -1) {
    classes.push('xdsoft_sunday');
}
```

Then, create a jQuery as follow.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    onGenerate:function( ct ) {
        jQuery(this).find('.xdsoft_date.xdsoft_sunday')
            .addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
    },
    timepicker: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

onGenerate:function( hu ) {
jQuery(this).find('.xdsoft_date.xdsoft_day_of_week0').addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
},